# Finding array of matches

Tags: excel-formula

In Google Sheets how can I get all possible matches for a value? I came up with something that gives me to first match or an NA, but not both matches (ideally in separate cells)

```
=iferror(MATCH(A2&"",Subjective_Photo!B:B,0),"NA")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Match stops looking after the first match.
The only way to get more than one result is to run multiple matches.
This of course has the tendency to be inconvenient if you want to match an unknown number of occurrences unless you are willing to extend the number of lookups every time you have more occurrences than the old number of performed lookups.

A way to do that would be the offset command

```
A    B    B(Formula)
1    1    =IFERROR(MATCH(1,A1:A8,0),"NA")
2    5    =IFERROR(MATCH(1,OFFSET($A$1:$A$8,B1,0),0)+B1,"NA") (drag it down from here)
3    8    =IFERROR(MATCH(1,OFFSET($A$1:$A$8,B2,0),0)+B2,"NA") 
4    N/A  =IFERROR(MATCH(1,OFFSET($A$1:$A$8,B3,0),0)+B3,"NA")
1 
5
6
1
```

If you want all results returned in an array that is possible only with vba